# How can I achieve a clean transparent alpha using cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, transparency, shadows

[image]

I've added a plane with a clip of the smoke on it. I also turned off the shadows from the object as I don't need 'em. After I set up the alpha material it looks clean, but when I spread the plane on some area, using geometry nodes, my alpha becomes a bit dirty, not fully transparent.

What could I possibly forget?
Original plane with a texture
[image]

And the plane instances in geometry nodes:
[image]

Comment: don't you need to increase the Transparency value in the Render panel > Light Paths > Max Bounces?

Comment: Yep. You're right. There weren't enough samples. Thanks =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the *Transparency* value in the *Render panel > Light Paths > Max Bounces*:

[image]